# add more information to database without making a new database

Tags: javascript, php, database

I would like to know how users can add multiple images and new data. For example on the site that I'm doing, you can make a design and when you finish you upload it to the database along with your email address title of the design, keywords ect.

I would like to know how its possible to let the user create more designs and named them all in the same database just retrieve them with an email address. I would like to make a limit of 14 designs per email address. But with the database and code that I have now, it only lets one design it just updates every time a new design is created.

Can someone show me the way on how to do this? If you need more information please ask, thank you.

Here is my code:

```
$query='UPDATE shirt_table SET   images="'.$_FILES['file4']['name'].'", images1="'.$_FILES['file1']['name'].'", images2="'.$_FILES['file2']['name'].'", images3="'.$_FILES['file3']['name'].'"
WHERE email= "'.$_SESSION['email'].'"';

if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: I'd advise that you do not save files directly in the database. Upload the design files to a secured directory on your site and save the paths to the uploaded files in the database. That should make things easier.

Comment: @SUNNYben i dont save my files to databse i save them to a folder and just the name to database.

Comment: My bad, didn't look at it very well. In that case, why not insert into multiple rows. Before saving a particular design, you can do a count to know how many designs have been saved by a particular email address and therefore restrict when it's up to 14.

Comment: @SUNNYben how do i do that can you please show me?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the uploaded files have different names, you'll have to list the expected file names internally as an array and loop through it that way.

Another thing you need to take care of is when the user has like 13 designs uploaded already and wants to add 4 more designs. You need to decide if you will reject all or add only one. Here is an example I believe you can modify to your taste.

```
/*

CREATE TABLE `shirt_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email_address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_path` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

*/

<?php

include("lib/dbcnx.inc.php");
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $begin = 1;
    $end = 5;
    $max_uploads = 14;

    $sel_query = "select count(*) from shirt_table where email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sel_query);
    echo $sel_query."<br/>";
    $numrows = $result->num_rows;
    $counter = 0;
    if ($numrows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        $counter = $row[0];
    }

    if ($counter < $max_uploads) {
        $saved_dir = "designs/";    

        $design_files = array($_FILES['file4']['name'], $_FILES['file3']['name'], $_FILES['file2']['name'], $_FILES['file1']['name']); 
        $query = "INSERT INTO shirt_table (email, image_path, date_created) values ";

        for ($i=$begin; $i<=$end; $i++) {
            $query = $query ."('".$email."', '".$saved_dir.$design_files[$i-$begin]."', now())";

            if ($i < $end)
                $query = $query.", ";               
        }

        echo $query."<br/>";

        if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }

        $mysqli->close();
    } else {
        echo "You have exceeded ...";
        $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
```